# How to correctly write this conditional phrase?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, subjunctive-mood

I’m struggling with a conditional clause. This one is easy:

> If I **were** you, I would do xyz ...

But I have these three statements:

> I **was** a student.
>
> It **was** my vacation.
>
> My professor **gave** me this assignment.

Now, I want to turn these three into conditional clauses:

> If I **were** a student, and it **were** my vacation, and my professor **gave** me this assignment, I would do xyz ...

Somehow, this doesn’t sound right. How do I fix it? (I want to keep the informal, conversational tone denoted by the repeated *and*)

Comment: Don't see what's wrong with your sentence myself, other than possibly having to "if it were"s in the same sentence sounds slightly over-pedantic to my ears.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the sentence.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with it beyond the repeated "and"s Jen points out. I think the question is how to rephrase a sentence made of those clauses in such a way as to keep it grammatical and keep/expand the informal, conversational tone, but make it less ungainly, which as a native speaker/reader/writer I will admit can be difficult with the subjunctive...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you begin with a sentence in the present and you turn it into an unreal situation with an *if* clause ("if x were true now, y would be true now too: but x isn't true now, and neither is y"), you normally use the *past subjunctive* + *would*:

> I am rich and I am arrogant
>
> => If I
> were rich, I'd be arrogant (but I'm
> not rich, and I'm not arrogant).

If you begin with a situation in the past and you turn it into an unreal situation in the past ("if x had been true then, y would have been true then too: but we know x wasn't true then, and y wasn't either"), you use the *past perfect subjunctive* and *would + have + past participle*:

> Russian communism worked and there
> were no economic problems
>
> => If
> Russian communism had worked, there
> wouldn't have been economic problems
> (but it didn't work, and there were
> problems).

Of course other combinations are possible, but this is the basic system. If you have a two- or threefold condition, as in your example, the tenses used depend on two things:

1. Is the main situation supposed to be an unreal situation in the past or in the present?
2. Are the parts of the condition (the *if* clauses) supposed to be happening at the same time, or did one happen before the others? If they didn't happen at the same time, those that were earlier than the "main" situation should be put in a tense that precedes the tense of the main situation (if possible): if the main situation is an unreal situation in the present, earlier parts should be in the past perfect subjunctive.

Let's assume that your example is about an unreal situation in the present ("if x were true now, y would be true now too"). It matters then whether all three things happened at roughly the same time—in this case, in the order by which they are mentioned: first A, then B, then C—or the assignment was given before the vacation.

If you were given this assignment before your vacation, this should be marked by putting the "assignment" *if* clause in the past perfect subjunctive ("had given"), to show that it happened before the "vacation" *if* clause. If your professor called you during your vacation to give you this assignment, you would simply use the past subjunctive ("gave").

Answer (score 5):

Do you perhaps like the sound of

> If I were a student, and it were my
>   vacation, and my professor had given
>   me this assignment, I would do xyz ...

any better?

Comment: +1 that's the only change I could see making if you're wanting to keep the "and..." repetition.

Comment: Thanks, this does sound better -- are both *gave* and *had given* correct grammatically, and if so, is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Yes - in this conditional future of yours, the giving would have happened in the past, rather than happening in the present.

Comment: *Were to have given* is also correct here, but some call it formal.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

> If I were a student and my professor gave me this assignment on my vacation, I would do xyz...

While it eliminates one of the *and*s I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your version is bad, really.  I'd probably do something like

> If I were a student and it was my
>   vacation, and if it was my professor that
>   had given me the assignment, I'd xyz
>   the xyz.

This isn't based on explicit rules, but on a sense of how it I could emphasize the nested conditionals as belonging within another (counterfactual?) condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that takes more liberties with your original clauses.

"If I were a student, and my professor assigned something over break, I'd [put it off 'til the last minute and complain about it]." (That's actually a true story ;_;...)

You lose a little informality with the single "and," but I think the other changes I made make up for it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since the context is informal, maybe you don't need to be quite so thorough and explicit.

I would try to find a way to write something like:

> If I were you, I would...
>
> If that happened to me, I would...
>
> If I had a professor like that, I would...
>
> I would...